Serilog global exception destructurer when WithoutReflectionBasedDestructurer
When WithoutReflectionBasedDestructurer() called the Serilog will not destructure exception which is not enlisted in exception destructurers (TargetTypes property). Is there a way to create global exception destructurer which would handle all exceptions handled by default by ReflectionBasedDestructurer?
